# How to use a CASE statement?

Tags: case, union

My goal is to create columns based upon dates found in different tables.
I used a union to combine the tables, which allowed me to pull a final set  and their observation.

I have tried inserting the following case statement on both sides of the union, but neither worked. The error is that one side of the union can not recognize the other table and throws an error.

Comment: `GROUP BY value_id` should be in the first part of the `UNION`, since it uses `MIN(date)`, not the second part.

Comment: And you don't need to use `DISTINCT` when you use `GROUP BY`, since the grouping ensures that it's distinct.

Comment: You can't reference `t1` in the `t2` query, unless you join the tables.

Comment: If you're using an expression in `WHEN`, you shouldn't put a column name before it.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Can you add some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: you need join instead of UNION

Comment: I added updated and images to my post so hopefully it makes it more clear. Basically I have 2 steps I want complete and I finished the first one with a union, which is why Im at this current query

Comment: Some other comments. Both tables have the same date name so I have to use table names before to specify and if there a way to get my current out put with a join I'm open to that I just could not do it